# Firebase push data with typeof function is return an error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Sorry for my English.

I am trying to add a `post` object, with a `func` property and a function value:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref('posts');
let func = function(){ alert('hi!') }
ref.push({
    author: 'some name',
    func: func,
});
```

But when adding, I get an error:

> Uncaught Error: Firebase.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'posts.func'`.

Although when I pass the text into the `func` property I have no error. Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realtime Database doesn't support storing function type values.  Values must be JSON-compatible: object, array, string, number, boolean, or null.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  Is there a way to save it as text?  And when called, run the function?

Comment: The database and its SDK will not do any of that for you. You have to manage that all yourself.

Comment: For example, using the function eval?

Comment: You could certainly try that.  The database is just going to store data.  It doesn't store actions to perform on data.  If you have specific code that isn't working the way you expect, please post it separately along with an explanation.

Comment: thanks, I will try, if something goes wrong I will post the code here.